# Value of a pointer change automatically C++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012

```
        int *Total_DealerPerGame = new int[5];
        Total_DealerPerGame = helper::local_search::dealer_assign(some pointers and variables);
        std::ofstream logging;
```

The value of pointer "Total_DealerPerGame" changes after running the the "ofstream logging" line automatically. What is the relation of this two line? what it should modify my value? what should I do to prevent it?

Comment: And unless you pass in `Total_DealerPerGame` into `dealer_assign` and it frees the memory, you have a memory leak. In other words, it is usually not a good thing to allocate memory and then immediately lose it.

Comment: Exactly, are you sure you want to do: Total_DealerPerGame = helper::etc..instead of *Total_DealerPerGame = helper::etc...

Comment: You're overwriting the prior value of your pointer (an address returned from `operator new []`) with the result of you function call. In short, you're leaking memory in two lines, abandoning the very dynamic memory you just allocated. This is in-al-likelihood a bug in itself.

Comment: I've tried what Martjin said, but the problem did not change, I defined an array and move the values of pointer to that and then delete it, now it's working. I know it doesn't sound totally right, but it worked. thanks.